# Running Hadoop jobs in an HPC cluster queue

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, hadoop-yarn, hpc, slurm

I am running a small HPC cluster with a traditional resource manager (SLURM) for users to queue their jobs.

I need users being able to launch Hadoop jobs without intervening with each other.

Hadoop 2.7 comes with its own resource manager YARN so having its daemons run permanently along with SLURM leads to possible resource conflicts.
I got Hadoop, that is HDFS and YARN, running fine on the cluster with Terasort speeding up almost twice on two datanodes comparing with one datanode. Now I would like to let other users run their Hadoop jobs safely, requesting the number of datanodes they need.

There is a special user hduser that starts all the Hadoop daemons, it has passwordless ssh access from management node to compute nodes.
Regular users has ssh access to management node only (SLURM launches workers using Munge authentication)

So the questions are:

1. Is it possible for a regular user to run Hadoop job after all the daemons are launched by hduser?
2. Is it possible to tell YARN nodemanager not to use a node unless user somehow 'locks' it? And then dedicate this node for that user's jobs only? My idea is that I can set and keep the lock via SLURM and let YARN do the rest.

So far I would like to avoid giving regular users permissions to ssh to compute nodes or start daemons there like in this guide:
http://www.glennklockwood.com/data-intensive/hadoop/on-hpc.html
but after all,

3. Do you think that would still be the easiest way?

Comment: It is not entirely clear what your goal function is. Secure, efficient, safe and easy to implement seem to be contradictory requirements.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, easy to implement is my main concern so far.